# Datastore parent child of the same entity

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore

I would like to have a datastore entity with a reference property back to the same entity. For example:

```
class Person(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(),
    parent = db.ReferenceProperty(Person,
            collection_name='parents')
```

So a person has a parent who is also a person (hopefully). This throws a `NameError: name 'Person' is not defined` exception. This example would only allow a person to have one parent, but it is just an example, not exactly what I am trying to model.

What is the best way to model this type of relationship with google app engine datastore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
parent = db.SelfReferenceProperty(collection_name='parents')
```